# JMS error: can not send into foreign destinations

Tags: java, jms, tibco

I use Spring-configured jms template with tibco jms library.
I get jms connection factory and topic with JNDI and these objects are not null. But when I try to send message or add listener I get this exception:

For listener:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Can not send into foreign destinations; nested exception is javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Can not send into foreign destinations
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:277)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:168)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:474)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.receiveSelected(JmsTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.receive(JmsTemplate.java:682)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.receive(JmsTemplate.java:674)
```

For sender:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Invalid or foreigndestination; nested exception is javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Invalid or foreigndestination
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:277)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:168)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:474)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:539)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:531)
```

Client app is working with the same topic without problems (so jms server is running). Do you have any ideas? I read about this exception in javadoc, but can't find how to understand the root issue and fix it.
Thanks

UPD: 
JMS-related part of config:

```
<bean id="JmsFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
          <property name="jndiName" value="${jms.factory}"/>
          <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory" />
          <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false" />
          <property name="jndiEnvironment">
            <props>
              <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${jms.namingProvider}</prop>
              <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">${jms.namingFactory}</prop>
              <prop key="java.naming.referral">${jms.namingReferral}</prop>
              <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">${jms.securityCredentials}</prop>
              <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">${jms.securityPrincipal}</prop>
            </props>
          </property>
      </bean>

        <bean id="JmsTopic" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
          <property name="jndiName" value="${jms.topic}"/>
          <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.Topic" />
          <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false" />
          <property name="jndiEnvironment">
            <props>
              <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${jms.namingProvider}</prop>
              <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">${jms.namingFactory}</prop>
              <prop key="java.naming.referral">${jms.namingReferral}</prop>
              <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">${jms.securityCredentials}</prop>
              <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">${jms.securityPrincipal}</prop>
            </props>
          </property>
      </bean>

      <bean id="UserCredentialsConnectionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
          <ref bean="JmsFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="username" value="${jms.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jms.password}" />
      </bean>

      <bean id="JmsTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory"
          ref="UserCredentialsConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="defaultDestination">
            <ref bean="JmsTopic"/>
        </property>
        <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true" />
      </bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have it configured so that it is attempting to create a destination rather than do a jndi lookup to get the destination that has been defined on the EMS instance.

You need to post your spring config to be sure though.

edit: if you set a destinationname on the JmsTemplate and provide it with a JndiDestinationResolver then it should work

Comment: Matt, I added spring config to first message

Comment: I had this problem about 2 yrs ago so I might be misremembering this but IIRC what happens here with tibco is that the reference passed to setDefaultDestination does not resolve to what you think it does (a reference to real destination obtained via jndi), instead it was some jndi object that is not a Destination instance. Running it under a debugger and sticking a breakpoint at the right place in spring code should make this obvious.

Comment: Matt, your update about JndiDestinationResolver solved my problem, thanks